# How to remove/delete scss/compass project?

Tags: ruby, unix, sass

I tried to set up a project according to [this tutorial](http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass). But it didn't work as it should so now I want to remove that project. How to do? What's the opposite of `compass create my_projectname` and `compass watch`? Or is it enough to delete all the files that were created after executing the create command line? I just don't want to waste server ressources. How to clean that "mess" up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only file that characterizes a Compass project is the config.rb, and it is primarily used to set environment variables (eg. such as paths to assets).  Provided you don't want to save any of the files that were created by setting up the project, you are free to delete them all.  Alternately, you can try fixing the project by making modifications to your config.rb.

Comment: ok, thx! Was just afraid of background processes that will slowdown the server ... ;)

Comment: Compass does not run any hidden processes, you have to explicitly tell it to run via `compass watch` or `compass compile`.

Comment: thought it looks for the deleted config file all the time. But if it stops after the file/files are  deleted it's all good ;)